# Let $R$ be a field. What are the $R$-submodules of $R \times R \ ?$

Tags: ring-theory

We know that $R$-submodule of $R$ are left ideals of $R.$

Is it also true that $R$-submodule of  $R \times R$ are left ideals of $R \times R\ ?$

Please advise on the correct approach to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that $R\times R$ is a field?  What is $R\times R$?  If you mean the product of rings, then it is not, as it has zero divisors.

Comment: Thanks for correction. So what can we say about the $R$-submodules of $R \times R ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is a field, $R$-module means $R$-vector space.

So you're asking what are the linear spaces in a vector space of dimension $2$.